# symfony 1.4 routing with sf_format

Tags: routes, symfony1

I'm doing mobile detection and setting sf_format to 'mobile' as per [these instructions](http://webmozarts.com/2010/09/07/creating-mobile-symfony-sites/).

But I'm having trouble creating separate routes for the mobile format. Is it possible to have two routes with the same url? The following setup isn't working for me:

```
mobile_homepage:
  url: /
  param: { module: mobile, action: index, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    sf_format: mobile

homepage:
  url: /
  param: { module: site, action: index }
```

The mobile_homepage route is always matched regardless of sf_format.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
  param: { module: mobile, action: index, sf_format: html }
```

You set the 'sf_format' to 'html' for this URL. Just write

```
  param: { module: mobile, action: index }
```

instead.

Also, when you use "requirements" it should be used like written here:

> http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2008/06/09/how-to-create-an-optimized-version-of-your-website-for-the-iphone-in-symfony-1-1

Comment: That's just it. Even if sf_format is set to 'html' it still matches the mobile_homepage route.